# ansible systemd start a service

Tags: ansible, systemd

I want to start a service on systemd service, but I have got an error, i don't understant how to resolved it

```
- name: Start service
  systemd:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: started
    enabled: yes
    daemon_reload: yes
  with_items:
    - a.service
```

I have got thies error :

> failed: [host] (item=a.service) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item",
> "changed": false, "item": "a.service", "msg": "Could not find the
> requested service a.service: host"}

Comment: Are you able to start the service manually on the host? Does the host actually recognise the service? If not then this isn't really an ansible problem.

Comment: yes indeed, I comment a copy of systemd file

Comment: What do you mean? You haven't provided a copy of your unit file. Could you post the output of `systemctl status a`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you don't use your variable as an jinja2.
[Ansible Doc - using-variables-with-jinja2](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables-with-jinja2)

You shall use your variable as `"{{ a.service }}"`

I.e.

```
  with_items:
    - "{{ a.service }}"
```

Comment: I think `a.service` is just a placeholder service name rather than an ansible variable.